# sqlite select awkward behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I use sqlite.NET(c#)
when i exec this statement

```
"SELECT id, date, team1, team2, finalScore, winner FROM matches WHERE team1 = @team OR team2 = @team AND date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate ORDER BY date DESC"
```

the `"team2 = @team"` is ignored, only selects if `"team1 = @team"`.
If I remove `"OR team2 = @team"` than the return query is empty while it shouldnt.
If i put `"team1 = @team OR team2 = @team"` into parenthesis then return empty query

here is all the code

```
public System.Data.DataTable searchMatches(string team, string fromDate, string toDate)
{
    SQLiteCommand cm = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT id, date, team1, team2, finalScore, winner FROM matches WHERE team1 = @team OR team2 = @team AND date BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate ORDER BY date DESC", cnlite);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team", team);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromDate", fromDate);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toDate", toDate);
    SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cm);

    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    sda.Fill(table);
    return table;
}
DataTable matches = db.searchMatches(sheetDataXlsx.Rows[i]["Ομαδα 1"].ToString(), matchDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
                                                    matchDate.AddDays(-90).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

PS the date is a string ("yyyy/MM/dd")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops), AND has higher precedence than OR.
So your query is equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE team1 = ? OR (team2 = ? AND date BETWEEN ...) ...
```

You have to manually add parentheses to force the correct evaluation order.